Existence of smooth triangulation for Riemannian 2-manifold
Most proofs that I can find of the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem for a compact Riemannian $2$-manifold $M$ always start with the assumption that $M$ has a smooth triangulation, i.e. a triangulation where the edges are smooth curves in $M$.
However I could not find a complete proof of the claim that all Riemannian $2$-manifolds admit a smooth triangulation.
I am aware of the existence of Radó's proof of existence of triangulations for topological $2$-manifolds. But those are not necessarily smooth, there would need to be an additional argument showing that a smooth triangulation can be obtained from the "continuous" one.
Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds (2nd Edition) sketches out a proof for the smooth case in Problem 9-5, which is presumably more elementary than Radó's proof, but it only provides some hints toward a proof. I'd be interested in a reference for a full proof of this argument, if for no other reason than to check my own proof based on the hints from Problem 9-5, once I manage to complete it. Since the existence of smooth triangulations seems to be a crucial step in the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem, I expect that there would be some reference to it somewhere.

Cairns proved existence of a smooth triangulation of any smooth manifold.

@MoisheKohan, surely there is a simpler proof for smooth surfaces that was known before Cairns.

Yes, the proof is simpler but I am not sure there is a reliable reference prior to Cairns (whose work in from 1930s), given the fact that even the modern definition of a smooth manifold was given only in 1920s. @Deane

@MoisheKohan, I’ll settle for more recent expositions.

Some references are provided here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17578/triangulating-surfaces

See for instance Theorem 10.6 in
Munkres, J. R., Elementary differential topology. Lectures given at Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Fall, 1961, Annals of Mathematics Studies. No. 54. Princeton, N.J.: Princeton University Press, XI, 107 p. (1963). ZBL0107.17201.
There, Munkres proves existence of smooth triangulations for differentiable manifolds of any dimension.
